# How can I set table row's height different each column in word via apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to create a table in my word document. In this table, I need something like this

[image: sample]

In this image, third row's third column has different height from first and second columns. I want to create something like this with apache poi but I don't find any solution for this.

My codes is here

```
        table.getRow(6).setHeight(630);
        table.getRow(6).getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);
        table.getRow(6).getCell(0).removeParagraph(0);  //Cell0
        XWPFParagraph row6Paragraph=table.getRow(6).getCell(0).addParagraph();
        row6Paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
        row6Paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun row6Run=row6Paragraph.createRun();
        row6Run.setFontFamily("Arial");
        row6Run.setFontSize(10);
        row6Run.setText("5) Engine Induction Date");
        row6Run.addBreak();
        String indDate="12-09-2018";
        row6Run.setText("  "+indDate);
        table.getRow(6).getCell(0).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4985));
        table.getRow(6).getCell(1).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(365));//cell1
        table.getRow(6).getCell(2).removeParagraph(0);  //Cell2
        row6Paragraph=table.getRow(6).getCell(2).addParagraph();
        row6Paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
        row6Paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun row6Run1=row6Paragraph.createRun();
        row6Run1.setFontFamily("Arial");
        row6Run1.setFontSize(10);
        row6Run1.setBold(true);
        row6Run1.setText("PART INFORMATION");
        table.getRow(6).getCell(2).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(4985));
```

Comment: A Word table can't have rows that are different heights in different columns unless you split or merge cells. But your sample looks like 2 separate tables beside each other, perhaps on a 2-column page.

Answer (score 2):

You should switch on showing non-printing characters in `Word` (¶). Without seeing those characters it is not really clear from your screen shot. But creating this using only one table by merging cells would be really hard, not only using `apache poi` but also using `Word`'s `GUI`. So I suspect this are three tables.

Table one is in a one column section and only contains one row having one cell containing the header.

Table two then is placed in a two columns section of the word document. Then the table breaks to the second column if needed. It has only one column and each row is as height as the content.

Table three is in a one column section again and only contains one row having one cell containing the footer.

Example using current `apache poi 4.1.2`:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

public class Word2ColumnPageWithTable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  //one column section
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("One column on top.");

  //table over full width of one column section
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  table.setWidth("100%");
  XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
  row.getCell(0).setColor("808080");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("Table Header");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setColor("FFFFFF");

  //paragraph with section setting for one column section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  CTSectPr ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
  CTColumns ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  //two column section
  //table over full width of one column in two column section
  table = document.createTable();
  table.setWidth("100%");
  row = table.getRow(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("SHORT CONTENT");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, which increases the row height.");
  row = table.createRow();
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("SHORT CONTENT");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  row = table.createRow();
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("SHORT CONTENT");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  row = table.createRow();
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("SHORT CONTENT");
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, so multiple lines will be needed, which increases the row height.");
  table.createRow().getCell(0).setText("Long content, which increases the row height.");

  //paragraph with section break continuous for two column section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
  ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
  ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
  ctColumns.setEqualWidth(STOnOff.ON);

  //one column section again
  //table over full width of one column section
  table = document.createTable();
  table.setWidth("100%");
  row = table.getRow(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).setSpacingAfter(0);
  row.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0).createRun().setText("TABLE FOOTER");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("One column on bottom.");

  //section setting continuous for one column section above and whole document from here on
  CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
  CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
  ctSectPr = ctBody.addNewSectPr();
  ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(STSectionMark.CONTINUOUS);
  ctColumns = ctSectPr.addNewCols();
  ctColumns.setNum(BigInteger.valueOf(1));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Word2ColumnPageWithTable.docx");  
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

This code produces a `Word2ColumnPageWithTable.docx` which looks like so:

[image]

Comment: I changed image in my question. Please check it again. If your answer  still same, I'll use it. Thanks

Comment: @demir5334: Creating this using only one table by merging cells would be really hard. Not only using `apache poi` but also using `Word`'s `GUI`.  So I suspect this are three tables. I have updated my answer to show an example of this.